# 2013 reusable workflow current item values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

My object is to create a 2013 reusable workflow that via rest updates a listitem in another list.

(This workflow will be copied via jsom and associated to newly created subsites, so it has to be reusable).

When I try to create variables from "Current item" the site column options are only standard. None of the custom site columns are available.

And there doesnt seem to be a way to use a specific content-type in SP2013 workflow.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a differnet approach.

- When a user creates a new project (subsite) the list item is created in the main "projectlist" and in the subsite "projectinfo" list.
- I made a custom editform to use in the subsites. So when the user edites the item I save it via jsom to subsite projectinfo (where it is edited), then on the callback I update the corresponding listitem in the main project site.
- Then i change window.location to the "target" from the query string.